# No default constructor exists for class "class"

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, language-lawyer

I have a diamond-shape set of derived classes:

```
   A
  / \
 B   C
  \ /
   D
```

---

```
class A {   //this is an abstract class
protected:
    const double commonVariable;

public:
    A(const double& commonVariable) : commonVariable(commonVariable) {}

    virtual double foo() const = 0; //pure virtual method
};
```

---

```
class B : virtual public A {    //inherited virtually: no duplicates in D
protected:
    const double& variableForB;

public:
    //here I have to call the constructor A() since there's no default constructor
    B(const double& commonVariable, const double& variableForB) : A(commonVariable), variableForB(variableForB) {}

    double foo() const override {   //this is just a common alias for the function in the instantiated class
        bar();  
    }

    double bar() const {
        //do stuff
    }
};
```

---

```
class C : virtual public A {    //inherited virtually: no duplicates in D
protected:
    const double& variableForC;

public:
    C(const double& commonVariable, const double& variableForC) : A(commonVariable), variableForC(variableForC) {}

    double foo() const override {
        spam(); 
    }

    double spam() const {
        //do stuff
    }
};
```

---

```
class D : public B, public C {
public:
    //even if I pass commonVariable twice no probs since A is virtually inherited
    D(const double& commonVariable, const double& variableForB, const double& variableForC) : B(commonVariable, variableForB), C(commonVariable, varibaleForC) {}   //<----THE ISSUE IS HERE (read below)

    double foo() const override {
        egg();
    }

    double egg() const {
        do stuff
    }

    //some other methods
};
```

---

```
//somewhere else inside the program

D specificObject = D(commonVariable, variableForB, variableForC);
A* genericObject = &D;
genericObject->foo();
```

Now, everything works fine except for one thing.

Inside class D's constructor I get the following error:
*no default constructor exists for class "A"*

Writing it in this way instead actually works:
D(const double& commonVariable, const double& variableForB, const double& variableForC) : A(commonVariable), B(commonVariable, variableForB), C(commonVariable, varibaleForC) {}

Shouldn't A's constructor be automatically called when I call B's constructor and C's constructor?

I can't understand why this redundancy is required... If it was a 10-class tree I would've had to call the parents' constructors 10 times for every derived class.

Anyway, I'm quite new to the polymorphism world, so any suggestions about how to improve these classes would be more than appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `C` has a "constructor" whose name is `B`

Comment: The problem is that _both_ B and C try to intialize A, and C++ doesn't know which to use.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the **real code** that you are describing.  This code has [very many errors](https://godbolt.org/z/WdPeKv).

Comment: Unrelated: As a newcomer to polymorphism, it's worth pointing out that when you find yourself in a position like this most of the time there's something wrong in the project design.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 thank you, it was just a typo while I was minimalizing it

Comment: @MooingDuck I think this isn't the problem, since A is virtually inherited

Comment: For virtual inheritance, the most derived class is responsible for invoking the constructor of the mutually shared virtual base class.

Comment: @user4581301 thank you for the advice. Anyway, my code actually works with the correction at the end of the question... I was just wondering why it doesn't work the other way

Comment: tip: compile and inspect the error message after minimalizing it. Otherwise typos might slip in that make your code produce errors on something unrelated

Comment: @Eljay is this also true for a class derived from D? (I mean, should E also call the constructor of A)

Comment: Correct.  The error message is due to the most derived class attempting to construct `A` by using the default constructor `A()`, but that constructor does not exist in `A`.

Comment: @Eljay thanks again. If you want to write an answer explaining this, I will accept it! Link me some guide that explains that too because I can't find anything like that on google...

Comment: I'll let someone else cobble together a comprehensive answer, since I'm pressed for time.  A `language-lawyer` (tag) would get the attention of someone familiar with the standard and could cite chapter-and-verse.  The difference in behavior of non-virtual vs virtual inheritance was something I learned a long time ago, probably out of Stroustrup's The C++ Programming Language book (great book!).

Comment: @Eljay I've been thinking about reading that book for a while... I will buy it sooner or later. Thank you again

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but `A` is an **abstract class** because it has a **pure virtual function**. There is no such thing as a pure virtual class.

Comment: If you want a reference to the standard, see [A: Does virtual inheritance force a base class to be default constructible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33574389). For a less lawyer-y reference, try [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class#Virtual_base_classes): *"All virtual base subobjects are initialized before any non-virtual base subobject, so only the most derived class calls the constructors of the virtual bases in its member initializer list".*

Comment: @JaMiT thank you very much! Your links have been useful. As said to Elijay, if you want to write an answer, I will accept it

Comment: @Eljay , JaMit anyway there's still one thing I cannot understand: if I remove the call to `A(commonVariable)` from the constructors of B or C, I still get that error. But the most-derived class is D. Why?

Comment: Because `A` does not have a default constructor.

Comment: @PellegattaSimone I'm inclined to consolidate answers in the proposed duplicate, so I'll refrain from posting an answer here. As for `B` and `C`, they *could* be the most-derived class for an object (e.g. define `B b;`), so their constructors have to be defined to handle that. (I forget if an abstract class'  constructor would need a valid call to a virtual base class constructor -- I think there's a question here on SO about that. Plus, it's easy to experiment. :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If A didn't had its default constructor deleted (by defining *any* constructor), this code would work. Either you have to call A constructor in initialization list of D.

In case of virtual inheritance, instances of  B and C are subobjects of class D, but they don't contain subobject of class A. Instead a single instance of A is subobject of D.

This way there is only one A in D, which solves so called cursed diamond at cost of B,C and D no longer having a standard memory layout ("memcpy-able") even if it didn't had any virtual members and D should have access to constructor of A to be able initialize it.

Comment: *"In case of virtual inheritance, instances of B and C are subobjects of class D, but they don't contain subobject of class A. Instead a single instance of A is subobject of D."* are you sure about that? First, I can access A's properties even from within B and C. Second, I get the same error if I do not call A's constructor from within B or C

Comment: @PellegattaSimone being subobject refers to memory layout (being inside of storage), not to access. You can access them due courtesy of vtable  in them, which would point to same A. If inheritance is not virtual , each of them would contain own copy of A (in beginning of storage, usually):  `D { B{A} C{A} }`. A virtual inheritance: `D { A B{ptr-to-A} C{ptr-to-A}  }`. Standalone B would be `B{ptr-to-A .... A}`. Actual layout is implementation-defined.

Comment: @PellegattaSimone in fact, everything is even more complex, there is a single table and B and C  have a pointer to it, table points to A and all members defined in D. That's why you can't tear a base object from derived object's storage by memcpy if base object had virtual members, it's not an equivalent of standalone instance.

Comment: I got it! Thank you... So, this implies that any ***non virtual*** class derived from A has to call A's constructor (in my case explicitly), since it could be directly instantiated and it would be the most derived class, am I right?

Comment: @PellegattaSimone Yes, they have to construct it,  it is their member, kinda, a subobject by definition (there is line about it in standard). Your B and C do that actually

Comment: While this is not the case for non-virtual classes, since the less direct child of the class is the only one with the task of initializing it, is it?

Comment: @Pellegatta Simone mm, no quite? only "next to kin" , direct child would need to initialize it.  D in your case is virtually inherited, because B and C were, so it have to babysit A.  In non virtual inheritance,  D would initialize B and  B would initialize A. If B would initialize A in former case, what C should do?

Comment: That's what I meant... I expressed myself badly. Thanks again anyway, I finally understood everything!